# Is there a name or a phrase for not being able to think like a new user?

Tags: novice-users

I'm thinking of when you have too much knowledge about how something works to see it the way someone who had never seen it or something like it before would see it.

I know I've read about this before but can't think where. The phrase that popped into my head was "expert's dilemma" but Googling that it looks like it refers to something else, and I think I'm getting confused with "innovator's dilemma". It's possibly related to learnability vs discoverability or the difference between expert and novice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> “Knowledge Blindness” —and its extreme form “Expert Blindness” — refer to the things that people who are knowledgeable can’t see because they can’t experience what it’s like not to know: such as what words beginners don’t understand, how difficult a task is to do or learn, distinctions that non-experts can’t discriminate and appreciate, and implications  that are dependent on advanced knowledge.

Source: http://mnav.com/expert-blindness/